# How to use Spring OAuth2 JWT Token?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, jwt

We want use the Spring OAuth2 JWT Token support. Our architecture is as follows: Spring just provides a REST-interface and the frontend is built with AngularJS which queries the Spring-REST-Interface. For authorization purpose our frontend-team wants to use JWT. So I have taken a look on the Spring OAuth2 JWT support and still do not really know how to talk with the frontend about JWT-Tokens. After reading a little tutorial I have implemented this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("defaultAuthorizationServerTokenServices")
private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); 
    //TODO comments
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    //@Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous() || hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')")
                   .checkTokenAccess("hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authManager).accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("my-trusted_client")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60)
        .and()
        .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "trust")
            .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value")
        .and()
        .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .secret("secret");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how the workflow is. What I guess: The frontend access the /oauth/authorization endpoint to authorize its token and then the Spring backend has to check every time a resource is requested the JWT-Token if it's authorized to access the resource? Right? So how can I tell Spring to check the token when a REST-endpoint is requested? I have tried it with

```
@RequestMapping("/projects")
@PreAuthorize("oauthClientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')")
public String getProjects() {
    return "";
}
```

But it seems not to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the new `spring-cloud-samples`'s [sso](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sso) sample. To me this was the best sample to play with to understand how it is done.

Also once you get your head around it, you can read [this](https://beku8.wordpress.com/2015/03/31/configuring-spring-oauth2-with-jwt-asymmetric-rsa-keypair/) tutoiral, which is bit more technical & more about how to do it with RSA assymetric keypairs.